# Storing data in shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have a need to store a list of e-mails in a shell script.  This script will get called and passed a customer number.  depending on the customer number I want to populate a variable based on the passed in customer number.

I am not sure how to accomplish this and have been looking.

command example

```
gcb "type" "customernumber" "date"
```

I want to pull an e-mail associated with that customer number and populate a variable with it.
I would prefer this get stored in the script and not in a separate file if possible.

@shellter

So as you can see above my command has the customer number as $2,  i am trying to get the email finder to work with that in mind.  So I created a script to test the e-mail finder function with.  It works fine as you have it below, but if i want it to look for $2 == cust_id it returns nothing.  Here is my code below.

```
#!/bin/sh
#case $# in 0 ) echo "usage: myEmailFinder2 CustID" ; exit 1 ;; esac
cfgDir="/verification"

# given cust file like
# cust_id "\t" email_addr
fn_myEmailFinder() {
       awk -F"\t" -v cust_id="$2" '{if ($2 == cust_id) {print $3}}'     /verification/custlist.cfg
       }


emailAddr=$( fn_myEmailFinder "$1")
echo $emailAddr
```

The command I run to test this is this

```
sh emailtest.sh test 90624
```

My config file is layed out like this, tab delimited

```
CustomerNumber  CustomerName  Email
```

I am going to store more data in this file to populate other variables,  I'm sure once i get this figured out, I can sort out the other data.

I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: There's a gadget called a 'database' that is good for storing data.  It is better than trying to store the data in a script in all sorts of ways, not least of which is that the data can be maintained separately from the script and reused by other applications — neither of which is possible (or easily possible) if you store the data in a shell script.  It also sounds like you want to store email addresses, rather than emails, in the script.  The difference is the size of the objects being stored, and the formatting.

Comment: If you're going to write a script, show us your code. If you want recommendation for a ready software, there's software-recommendations site on stackexchange.

Comment: Most things are possible with shell scripts, but .... storing data in the script is not considered something suitable for production environments. The risk of modifying the script is increased each time you have to edit the script to change the data. If you *really* must, then look at `grep "$uid" <<EOF line1^Jline2^Jline3^EOF` You'll have to find out about `HERE` documents (represented by the `<<EOF` here) and realize that `^J` is the line-feed char `\n` that makes separate lines in a file. **Then** you'll have to make a record layout for extract the field that you need Good luck.

Comment: I missed that  you had updated your question. (For future reference, notices for usernames (@ shellter) are only sent from comments, not the body of a question)  Are things working now? the `-v cust_id="$2"` is a problem. At that "level" the `$2` is the 2nd option on the cmd line. If your only passing in custID to lookup, then revert to `-v cust_id="$1"`. Glad your making progress.

Comment: And finally, in the future, avoid getting  your question downvoted. Read the help pages -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to post a well formed question -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: cust_id will always be passed as $2 to this command.  I have not been able to make this work in that scenario yet.  so `-v cust_id="$2"` is making "cust_id" equal to the 2nd option on the command correct?  So wouldn't the awk statement need to be.  `($1 == cust_id)`

Comment: I'm confused now ;-) If you still need help, I recommend posting a new question with small sample inputs, expected output, your code, calling the code from cmd-line with args, the current output, error messages and your commentary on where you think the problem is. (Use the `{}` edit tool at the top left of the edit box to format your code and data.) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This script will get called and passed a customer number.

```
myEmailFinder "$CustID"
```

> I want to populate a variable based on the passed in customer number.

```
emailAddr=$( myEmailFinder "$CustID")
```

> I want to pull an e-mail associated with that customer number and populate a variable with it.
>
> I would prefer this get stored in teh script and not in a separate file if possible.

Using a database is preferred, but   ....    per your written specification, try this

```
cat myEmailFinder
#!/bin/bash
case $# in 0 ) echo "usage: myEmailFinder CustID" ; exit 1 ;; esac

# given cust file like
# cust_id "\t" email_addr
fn_myEmailFinder() {
    awk -F"\t" -v cust_id="$1" '{
         if ($1 == cust_id) {
                 print $2
         }
        }' <<-EOF
          1       user1@myCorp.com
          2       user2@myCorp.com
          5       user3@myCorp.com
        EOF
        #--^tabCh^---make sure you put a real tab char between custID and emailAddr
    #tabCh-TabCh--- data indented with TabChars. EOS indented with **only** tabCh.

#send an email to cust in $1
emailAddr=$( fn_myEmailFinder "$1")
mailx -S "Test Email" "$emailAddr" <<-EOM
   Here is the body of an email addressed to $emailAddr with CustID=$custID
EOM

#end of script
```

The block delimited by EOF is the place to store your custID and associated email Addresses. One per line, tab-delimited. The Indents on each line should be done with tab chars. The closing EOF line must be done ONLY with tab chars.

A preferable solution would be to store the "lookup table" in a separate file. That would look like

```
cat myEmailFinder2
#!/bin/bash
case $# in 0 ) echo "usage: myEmailFinder2 CustID" ; exit 1 ;; esac

cfgDir="/usr/local/data"

# given cust file like
# cust_id "\t" email_addr
fn_myEmailFinder() {
    awk -F"\t" -v cust_id="$1" '{
         if ($1 == cust_id) {
                 print $2
         }
        }' "$cfgDir"/emaillist.cfg

#send an email to cust in $1
emailAddr=$( fn_myEmailFinder "$1")
mailx -S "Test Email" "$emailAddr" <<-EOM
   Here is the body of an email addressed to $emailAddr with CustID=$custID
EOM
```

where `emaillist.cfg` is laid out as above, tab-delimited.

IHTH

Comment: Thanks,  I will try this out.  I am new to shell so i was not sure if storing in the script was possible,  i will create a file to store all the data.  I should be able to just run that function inside my already existing shell script/command correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe you should be able to run the function in your script. Note that if your file has more than 2 columns (or that the ID or emailAddr are not in first and second column) you'll need to change the `$1` and/or `$2` to extract the data you need. Data must be tab delimited. I'd recommend that you copy paste just the `awk '{....}' file` part and make small changes to that to understand how it works. Then use the `emailAddr=$( fn_myEmailFinder "$userID")` to store values to variables. If you get stuck, post a new question. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks,  i am about to test this out.  I am aware of out $1, $2, and so forth work.  I appreciate all the help. I will return with my results.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -
''''echo "Customer number: $1"
X=$(/bin/env python $0 $1)
echo $X
exit
'''

customers = {
     42: 'customerA'
    ,43: 'customerB'
}

import sys
print customers.get(int(sys.argv[1]), '')
sys.exit(0)
```

:-|

> if [ "$1" = "42" ]; then X="CustomerA" ; fi
>
>      if [ "$1" = "43" ]; then X="CustomerB" ; fi